# Why singleton getInstance method has to be public static in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am just curious why a Singleton class getInstance (or whatever you want to call it) needs to be public static. It only needs to be static not public if that singleton should only be used with in the same package or is my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: If the singleton instance needs to be used in only the same package then it need not be public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need it public, don't make it public!

As long as you can use it where you need it you'll be fine.

Comment: I don't know. It's better to have consistent access modifiers on members, and skip the public on the class where required.